# Is it considered as bad practice to update observers in fileds' setters?

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Let's say I have an object `Subject` which consists of a list of its observers and an `int` field:

```
package example.template.pattern.observer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Subject {

    private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
    private int state;

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void attach(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void notifyAllObservers() {
        for (Observer observer : observers) {
            observer.update();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to notify all of them after every 'set' operation of `state`'s field. The most common code I know for performing such an operation is something like this:

```
Subject subject = new Subject();
subject.add(newObserver);
subject.setState(newState);
subject.notifyAllObservers();
```

But because I want an update every time I set a new value to the `state` I changed a code a little.

Changed `notifyAllObservers()` access modifier to private:

```
private void notifyAllObservers() { ... code }
```

And added a new extra line to the `state`'s setter:

```
public void setState(int state) {
    this.state = state;
    notifyAllObservers();
}
```

Is the code above considered as a bad practice?

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Comment: (typo "list of it's observers" - possessive its?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't this be fine?

In my opinion, this is actually considered a good practice. You will have a very high chance of forgetting to call `notifyAllObservers` after maybe a month or so. Or even worse, someone else might use your code and don't know that they should call `notifyAllObservers` after setting the state. If this happens, your code might not work as expected. That's why you should put `notifyAllObservera` in the `setState` method. This way, you and other people don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine, **but proceed with care**

--

What if one of the `Observer` decide to remove itself as a result of receiving the notification? (Yes, I know, the posted code doesn't show a `detachObserver` but rarely missing this method is a good idea)

So, under the assumption there is one, then:

```
class SatisfiedObserver {
  Subject observed;

  public SatisfiedObserver(Subject subject) {
    this.observed=subject;
    subject.attach(this);
  }

  public void update() {
    // Doing some work
    // Well, I'm satisfied
    this.observed.detach(this);
    // Now, innocent as it looks, **THIS** will blow 
    // the for cycle in Subject.notifyAllObservers() with a
    // ConcurrentModificationException
  }
}
```

The solution:

```
public void notifyAllObservers() {
    Observer[] obses=this.observersArray();
    for (Observer observer : obses) {
        observer.update();
    }
}

protected final Observer[] observersArray() {
  Observer[] retval=new Observer[0];
  synchronized(this.observers) {
    // we don't want other threads to screw up observers while we take a copy
    // And since we don't want that, we'll nee to synchronize the attach
    // and detach as well: its not like the observers will
    // attach/detach all the time to fear serious
    // performance impact
    retval=this.observers.toArray(retval);
  }
  return retval;
}

public void attach(Observer o) {
  if(null!=o) {
    synchronized(this.observers) {
      this.observers.add(o);
    }
  }
}
public void detach(Observer o) {
  if(null!=o) {
    synchronized(this.observers) {
      this.observers.remove(o);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Other things worth considering:

1. `Observer` instances registered to multiple `Subject`s - how do they know which subject changed status (consider `Observer.update(Subject who)`)
2. what will you do if one of the `Observer`s throws while in `update`? Will you stop notifying the others and let the exception bubble? Catch the exception, continue the notification and rethrow?(then what if many observers throw?)... Decisions, decisions...
3. why the `Observer`s should receive updates if no actual state change occurred? Consider

```
    public void setState(int state) {
      if(this.state = state) {
        this.state = state;
        notifyAllObservers();
      }
    }
```